# Adicionando tags data ao button com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso adicionar `tags` `data` ao meu `button` quando passo o mouse sobre ele, ja consegui pegar o movimento de `mouse hover` agora preciso adicionar as `tags`, que são:

```
data-trigger="hover" 
data-toggle="popover"
data-placement="bottom"
data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
data-original-title="Popover Title"
```

Então meu button no final deve ficar assim:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover"
        data-placement="bottom"
        data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
        title="" data-original-title="Popover Title">
   Meu botão
</button>
```

[image: e]

O `$(this)` acessa o dom de meu botão. Porem preciso colocar o link na `tag span` como na imagem ascima.

Meu código esta assim:

```
eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view){
  $(jsEvent).attr("data-trigger","hover");
  $(this).attr("data-toggle","popover");
  $(this).attr("data-placement","bottom");
  $(this).attr("data-content","Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.");
  $(this).attr("ata-original-title","Popover Title");
}
```

Eu preciso que os atributos seja adicionados ao filho do `$(this)` pois o `$(this)` é a `tag a`, e o que precisa receber é o filho de `a`, `span`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa sem precisar usar o `attr` seria o próprio `data()` do JQuery.

De acordo com a documentação:

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

No seu caso, fica algo como:

```js
$("#botao").on("mouseover", function() {
  $(this).data("trigger", "hover")
    .data("toggle", "popover")
    .data("placement", "bottom")
    .data("content", "Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.")
    .data("original-title", "Popover Title");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="botao">
  Passe o mouse
</button>
```

Utilizando o `data()` seu HTML fica mais limpo, uma vez que esses dados não aparecem no formato `data-*`. Tudo fica salvo em memória associada aquele elemento específico.

Pra poder utilizar depois os dados salvos basta usar o próprio método `data()` com o primeiro parâmetro sendo o a "chave" para acessar o dado armazenado.

`$("#botao").data("trigger"); // retorna 'hover'`

**UPDATE**

Para refletir a mudança da pergunta, para colocar os dados dentro de `span` e não dentro do `button`, basta utilizar a função `find()`.

Fica assim:

```js
$("#botao").on("mouseover", function() {
  var myspan = $(this).find("span");
  myspan.data("trigger", "hover")
    .data("toggle", "popover")
    .data("placement", "bottom")
    .data("content", "Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.")
    .data("original-title", "Popover Title");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="botao">
  Passe o mouse
  <span>Reunião Urgente</span>
</button>
```

Nesse momento, quem está recebendo os dados são a tag `span`, não o botão.
*OBS: Se existir mais de uma tag `span` dentro do botão, a variável `myspan` conterá referência a todos os `span` capturados.*

Caso queira utilizar o recurso `popover` do bootstrap, deve executar o `popover` sempre depois de ter personalizado a tag com os dados que você quer.
Ou você pode rodar o `popover` com seus próprios `options`.

Vejamos:

```js
$("#botao").on("mouseover", function() {
  var myspan = $(this).find("span");
  myspan.popover({
    placement: "bottom",
    content: "Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.",
    trigger: "hover"
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="botao">Passe o mouse <span> Reunião urgente </span> 
</button>
```

Dessa forma você consegue adicionar o popover em tempo de execução.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Brother me ajuda aqui, o $(this) está indo na tag a, porém preciso coloca-la no span que fica dentro do a, como faço isto ?

Comment: Utilize`var span = $(this).find("span");`. Nesse momento você terá acesso ao span (mas lembre-se que dessa forma, se tiver mais de 1 span, a variável `span` terá referência a todos. Mas se for de acordo com o que você postou na foto, deve funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou, porém ainda não esta aparecendo o toolipop, tenho que verificar qual meu erro

Comment: Você precisa rodar o tooltip depois de ter adicionado os dados.
Executar o tooltip antes e depois adicionar os dados não funciona mesmo.
Uma dica, precisa mesmo adicionar os dados realmente em tempo de execução?
Não pode ser antes? Manualmente?

Comment: É porque tudo é dinamico, não consigo montar o html antes mesmo disso, preciso monta e ja mostrar o toolpop

Comment: Entendi, então faça como eu falei. Primeiro adicione os dados como o @LocalHost respondeu e somente depois rode o tooltip.
Alternativamente, você pode rodar o tooltip com options.
Ficaria algo como `$(this).find("span").tooltip({placement:"bottom", title:"Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."});` Dai dessa forma, não precisa se preocupar em adicionar os dados no HTML, ja roda o tooltip de acordo com seus requisitos (options).

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51562/discussion-between-andrew-ribeiro-and-renan-rodrigues).

Comment: Teria como adicionar isto a resposta ?

Answer (score 2):

Seria isso?

```js
$("#botao").on("mouseover",function(){
  $(this).attr("data-trigger","hover");
 $(this).attr("data-toggle","popover");
 $(this).attr("data-placement","bottom");
 $(this).attr("data-content","Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.");
$(this).attr("ata-original-title","Popover Title");


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="botao">
Passe o mouse
</button>
```

Comment: deixe eu testa para verificar

Comment: Atualizei minha pergunta olhe la

Comment: @RenanRodrigues, como você fez até agora, coloque o código. O exemplo que coloquei não deu certo?

Comment: Cara deu e não deu, o código  esta adicionando, porém esta adicionando em lugar errado, na verdade meu $(this) não é quem precisa receber as tags e sim um dos filhos dele o span